# issue in sending private message to facebook friends with facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am working on a facebook application , i need to send a message to user facebook friends , is that possible to send without opening the facebook send message dialog box, because when i use facebook SDK it uses its ui to preview , i also tried using direct url

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=658662621626&name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&recipients[0]=466565&link=http://www.redbuffer.com&redirect_uri=http://www.example.net/FB-app/
```

is their any other method by which i will be able to send private message
to facebook friends

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is a resounding heck no.  The reason?  They would open themselves up to spamming if they allowed API's to directly send messages.  Just a guess though.

Comment: do u think is their any other method , sort of using SMTP server of facebook , is that possible ??